# Get next and previous entries while looping through Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get next and previous iteration values while looping through Pandas Series? I'd like to calculate difference between next and previous index, along the lines of:

```
data = pd.Series([1,2,4,2,5], index = [100,120,130,140,170])
for idx in data.iteritems():
    delta = idx.next()[0] - idx.previous()[0]
    # do other stuff
```

I would treat first and last elements separately, so for now let's ignore them.

Comment: FYI always try to vectorize, most pandas (and numpy) functions will operate on the whole structure at once, much faster that way. though it requires sometimes to think a bit differently how to approach problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
In [55]: for i in range(data.size):
   ....:     print 'now', data[data.index[i]]
   ....:     if i==0: continue
   ....:     if i==data.size-1: continue
   ....:     print '  last: ', data[data.index[i-1]]
   ....:     print '  next: ', data[data.index[i+1]]
   ....:     

now 1
now 2
  last:  1
  next:  4
now 4
  last:  2
  next:  2
now 2
  last:  4
  next:  5
now 5
```

Comment: This is what I end up doing. I'm using data.index[i] itself instead of data[data.index[i]] though. But this is the right idea, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These work for you?

```
In [32]: data = pd.Series([1,2,4,2,5], index = [100,120,130,140,170])

In [33]: data
Out[33]: 
100    1
120    2
130    4
140    2
170    5
dtype: int64

In [34]: data.diff()
Out[34]: 
100   NaN
120     1
130     2
140    -2
170     3
dtype: float64

In [35]: data-data.shift(1)
Out[35]: 
100   NaN
120     1
130     2
140    -2
170     3
dtype: float64

In [36]: data-data.shift(-1)
Out[36]: 
100    -1
120    -2
130     2
140    -3
170   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: sorry, it's next and previous index, not value. Also this seem to do current and next value, not next and previous...

Comment: But I get the idea, I can extract indices, shift them and create another series from which I'll take delta's.